# XML security configuration with Spring Boot fails with BeanDefinitionParsingException - Configuration problem

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to set up an XML based basic auth for all my REST endpoints.
But I'm getting an BeanDefinitionParsingException - Configuration problem (see stack trace below) when I start the spring boot application with XML resource.
Any ideas why?

```
ERROR 151468 --- o.s.boot.SpringApplication  : Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available. You need these to use <http>
Offending resource: class path resource [basic-auth.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.reportMissingWebClasses(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
```

My application is annotated with ImportResource:

```
...
@ImportResource("classpath:/basic-auth.xml")
public class SpringBootApp() {
...
```

**basic-auth.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/securityNone" security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <http-basic/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="pw1" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

I already added spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-security-web, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-tomcat as dependencies.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter` seems pretty clear. So unless you are using pre-release versions of Spring BOot 3 and manually messing around with Spring Security dependencies that error shouldn't happen.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that clear. I also do not use a pre-relase of spring boot. Spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-security-web, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-tomcat, javax.servlet-api were added as dependencies. All dependencies should exist, but the spring boot class loader is not able load the class javax.servlet.Filter.

Comment: Please don't describe your dependencies show them, add your build file.